# Java 8 Compiled EAR containing EJB causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Payara

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, payara

I'm working on a Maven Java EE project that has been around for quite some time (10 years plus) and is currently boxed in by Java 7 - it runs on Glassfish 3.1.2 currently, and I'm running through IntelliJ via an EAR file containing several jars, including an EJB jar.

I've been trying a few migration paths that can hopefully lead the project into a supported version of Java (into 8, but hopefully onwards, via some baby steps).  So far, I've been trying both Glassfish and Payara 4.1.

The project will happily compile into Java 8 (`JDK1.8.0_181`), but when attempting to deploy to the running server, I am getting multiple deploy-breaking errors - **all of which are for EJB classes** along the same template of:

```
 Error in annotation processing: {0}.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/module/class/ejb/path/SomeClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.loadClass(CurrentBeforeParentClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:295)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:592)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:445)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:417)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.openWith(Archivist.java:290)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openWith(ApplicationFactory.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:882)
```

I've tried a few different things, summarised as:

- All runs fine on Glassfish 3.1.2 with `JDK 1.7_080`, but there are some 'warnings' similar to the above, but they don't affect deployment
- Neither Payara 4.1.2 nor Glassfish 4.1.1 will load when set to use `JDK 1.7_080`
- I have tried to compile with and without `maven-ejb-plugin 3.1` using `addClassPath`, manually checking the EJBs manifest.mf for presence of a class-path (with and without).
- I have checked the domain's application deploy contents for presence of the listed classes - they exist, are in the JARs, in the EAR (exploded and otherwise) and are in the correct location.
- I have tried being more explicit in the dependencies for the EJB module by  setting versions, just in case.

I've pretty much run out of ideas with this.

I'll admit that EJBs and Maven aren't my specialist subject, but every resource so far has led me to solutions that aren't the cause - is there anything else I should be trying?

**Edit/Update**

Some additional debugging in ClassLoader suggests that the Classpaths are resolving to, for example `glassfish/domains/mydomain/applications/lib/commons-net.jar`.

There is no `/lib/` directory in applications, only my `My-Application-1.0-SNAPSHOT` directory, containing `META-INF` and the base package dir (`uk`).  The `lib` directory is, however, present in the `target` directory of my project's ear (alongside the `META-INF` dir and the `war`/`jar` files).

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward, this turned out to be the parent EAR not building correctly before deployment - the clue was in the last bit, where the contents of the application folder in Payara/Glassfish's 'domain' folder did not look representative of the EAR.

I eventually found this by debugging, rather than just googling what turned out to be a perfectly reasonable error, so there's probably a lesson in there.

Fixed the EAR, deployed and all worked.